# jquery break out element with before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element inside an element like this:

```
<div>
   <div class="contentBody">
      <img src="..." />
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to break out the image of the contentBody to get this result:

```
<div>
   <div class="contentBody">
   </div>
   <img src="..." />
   <div class="contentBody">
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
$('img').before('</div>').after('<div class="contentBody">')
```

However this does not work. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: you can unwrap then append 2 div

Comment: `</div>` is a closing tag, not an element, so you can't select it.

Answer (score 1):

Append the image to the parent of the `contentBody` then insert after it another `contentBody` div:

```js
$('img').appendTo($('.contentBody').parent()).after('<div class="contentBody">');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <div class="contentBody">
      <img src="..." />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.contentBody img').unwrap();
$('img').before('<div class="contentBody"></div>');
$('img').after('<div class="contentBody"></div>');
```

```css
.contentBody {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="contentBody">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

1. unwrap img using `.unwrap()`
2. add div using `.before()` and `.after()`

`UPDATE`

```js
$('.contentBody img').before('<div class="contentBody"></div>');
$('.contentBody img').after('<div class="contentBody"></div>');
$('.contentBody img').unwrap();
```

```css
.contentBody {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="contentBody">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Soviut first snippet is img unwrap first second is append first.